# Bootstrap mobile breakpoint expands nav

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, media-queries

I have a WordPress site which uses Bootstrap. For some reason, when I adjust my Chrome window, in mobile breakpoint (when the window is exactly the same width as the breakpoint), the mobile nav expands. When it's larger or smaller than the breakpoint, it collapses.

It's mostly annoyance, but I can't figure it out. Why does this happen?

EDIT:

This is the _variables.scss code:

```
$screen-xs:                  480px !default;
$screen-xs-min:              $screen-xs !default;
$screen-phone:               $screen-xs-min !default;
```

EDIT EDIT:

Changing the _variables.scss line:

```
$grid-float-breakpoint-max: ($grid-float-breakpoint -1) !default;
```

to

```
$grid-float-breakpoint-max: ($grid-float-breakpoint) !default;
```

solved the problem. @henrywright's solution is correct, thank you.

Comment: share your code or link to the site

Comment: @Muleskinner, unfortunately I can't link to the site since it's not published yet. I'll add the code but I'm afraid it doesn't help much since I can't pin point where the problem is located. That's why I hoped someone more familiar with Bootstrap than me could tell why this occurs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the [Customizer](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/#grid-system), try adjusting the value of `@grid-float-breakpoint`. This will modify the point at which the navbar becomes uncollapsed.

Comment: Thank you Henry. Do you have any idea, why is $grid-float-breakpoint-max: set to ($grid-float-breakpoint -1)? Why is it -1?

EDIT:

I mean why is it set to -1 by default in Bootstrap?

Comment: The reason `@grid-float-breakpoint-max` is set to `(@grid-float-breakpoint - 1)` by default is so the navbar starts collapsing **before** it becomes uncollapsed.